# Numba `nogil` + dask threading backend results in no speed up (computation is slower!)

Tags: python, multithreading, dask, numba

I'm trying to use [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) and [Dask](https://dask.org/) to speed up a slow computation that is similar to calculating the [kernel density estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) of a huge collection of points. My plan was to write the computationally expensive logic in a `jit`ed function and then split the work among the CPU cores using `dask`. I wanted to use the `nogil` feature of `numba.jit` function so that I could use the `dask` threading backend so as to avoid unnecessary memory copies of the input data (which is very large).

Unfortunately, Dask won't result in a speed up unless I use the `'processes'` scheduler. If I use a `ThreadPoolExector` instead then I see the expected speed up.

Here's a simplified example of my problem:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import numba
import dask

CPU_COUNT = os.cpu_count()

def render_internal(size, mag):
    """mag is the magnification to apply
    generate coordinates internally
    """
    coords = np.random.rand(size, 2)
    img = np.zeros((mag, mag), dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(len(coords)):
        y0, x0 = coords[i] * mag
        y1, x1 = int(y0), int(x0)
        m = 1
        img[y1, x1] += m

jit_render_internal = numba.jit(render_internal, nogil=True, nopython=True)

args = 10000000, 100

print("Linear time:")
%time linear_compute = [jit_render_internal(*args) for i in range(CPU_COUNT)]

delayed_jit_render_internal = dask.delayed(jit_render_internal)

print()
print("Threads time:")
%time dask_compute_threads = dask.compute(*[delayed_jit_render_internal(*args) for i in range(CPU_COUNT)])

print()
print("Processes time:")
%time dask_compute_processes = dask.compute(*[delayed_jit_render_internal(*args) for i in range(CPU_COUNT)], scheduler="processes")
```

And here's the output on my machine:

```
Linear time:
Wall time: 1min 17s

Threads time:
Wall time: 1min 47s

Processes time:
Wall time: 7.79 s
```

For both the processing and threading backends I see complete utilization of all CPU cores, as expected. But no speed up for the threading backend. I'm pretty sure that the jitted function, `jit_render_internal`, is not, in fact, releasing the GIL.

My two questions are:

1. If the `nogil` keyword is passed to `numba.jit` and the GIL cannot be released, why isn't an error raised?
2. Why doesn't the code, as I've written it, release the GIL? All the computation is embedded in the function and there's no return value.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: When I look at my CPU usage for the python process, when running `threads`, I can see that it's using all of my cores, but at this point, I'm not sure why it is running slowly. I can reproduce using a `concurrent.futures` thread pool, so it's just not dask

Comment: Something weird is happening here. on my laptop these are the results of timing: Linear 8.63s, Threads 11s, Process 2.1s

Comment: Yes that's approximately what I see as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, which is much faster and seems to fix the thread performance issue:

```
def render_internal(size, mag):
    """mag is the magnification to apply
    generate coordinates internally
    """
    coords = np.random.rand(size, 2)
    img = np.zeros((mag, mag), dtype=np.int64)
    for i in range(len(coords)):
        #y0, x0 = coords[i] * mag
        y0 = coords[i,0] * mag
        x0 = coords[i,1] * mag
        y1, x1 = int(y0), int(x0)
        m = 1
        img[y1, x1] += m
```

I've split the calculation of `x0` and `y0` up in the above. On my machine, the threads based solution is actually faster than the processes after the change.

Comment: Why does that make a difference?

Comment: Any thoughts as to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56926880/numba-nogil-true-threadpoolexecutor-results-in-smaller-speed-up-than-expecte

Comment: @DavidHoffman Really old question, but this should be because `x0, y0 = ...` produces a new, intermediate python tuple which requires the GIL. Your threads run in parallel, but busy-wait for the GIL to allocate the required tuple which effectively makes the application single-thread. The second tuple creation (the one casting to `int`) likely gets inlined by the compiler since you can easily pull the statement into the now split computation of `x0` and `y0` respectively, hence no GIL requirement.